# How to download 45 degree aerial images from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Is there any API for downloading 45 degree aerial images from Google Maps? If not is there any hack to take screenshots or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Bing Maps has the API for downloading 45 degree view as they call it Bird's Eye view. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer doesn't answer your question about how to get images from _google maps_ at all. "Use Bing" is a good workaround, but not really an answer to the question...

Answer (score 4):

`PrtScn` is the best hack I know of.

Beyond that, downloading lots of images from Google Maps violates their ToS, so it's probably not a good idea...you know, being illegal and all...

Comment: I don't want to download tons of images. Just a few hundreds at most. For example, Google Street View allows downloading 1k images per day.

Comment: @Mohammad, you will be violating the terms of service if you download any of the imagery, as it is not accessible via the API.  Even if it were available via an API, it would violate the terms of service.